# Remove a div from Material UI's Date Picker

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I use Material UI's basic Date Picker component in my project, but I need only the calendar block. Is there any way I can delete the div with the month and year representation and these arrows?

[image]

Comment: Post the code of the calendar. Obviously, it is possible

Comment: Hello @blazej this is the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/onggx?file=/demo.tsx How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I think you should do this, you should probably use a different ui component if your goal is to display a static calendar block that the user cannot navigate (since you plan on hiding the navigation controls), but the below javascript code snippet will allow you to *hide* the controls block/div:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("MuiCalendarPicker-root")[0].children[0].style["display"]="none";
```